# How to set initial size of JFace Dialog?

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I know that we can use `getInitialSize()` to set the initial size of a JFace Dialog.

The issue is that I have 2 monitors with different resolution (one is 2k monitor and another is 4k monitor which has high resolution).

I want to set size of a dialog in such a way that dialog should visible identically when I see in both the monitors. Basically I want to scale up my dialog to be visible properly in 4k monitor. How do I do this.

Comment: Is the 4k screen running scaled (2 x 1 or 1.5 x 1) or is it native resolution? For native resolution aren't you going to have to change all the font sizes etc. as well?

Comment: 4k resolution set is 3840x2160 and text size is set to 250%. All fonts is displayed properly but the issue is with dialog size.

Comment: Try running with `-Dswt.autoScale=exact` option to see if the automatic scaling will deal with 250%

Comment: Tried above command. Still issue is persisting.

Comment: `getShell().getMonitor().getZoom()` should give you the zoom percentage which can be used to adjust sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I was not able to find the exact solution, I found a workaround for by using `org.eclipse.jface.layout.PixelConverter`.

Example :

```
PixelConverter pc = new PixelConverter(control);
pc.convertWidthInCharsToPixels(number);
```

or

```
PixelConverter pc = new PixelConverter(control);
pc.convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(number);
```

Set the above code to `GridData.widthHint` or `GridData.heightHint`